# How django resolve the foreign key in its models.py?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am wondering how django decides which column or field will act as foreign key to another model in One to Many relationship.

```
class Department(models.Model):
  dept_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  dept_head = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  dept_abbrv = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Employee(models.Model):
  dept = models.ForeignKey(Department)
  emp_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Now how django knows which column of Department (dept_name, dept_head or dept_abbrv) will map to 'dept' in Employee. 
In my admin page of Employee details if I have to add a new employee, there is dropdown listing all Department.dept_name against 'dept'. How django decides that? Why it is not dropdown list of dept_head or dept_abbrv ?

Comment: It is mapped to the id field which Django creates automatically for models to act as primary key.

Comment: Thanks for answer Filip. Please see my reply to Kevin below, if you can help with that?

Answer (score 0):

Django will create an id as a primary key and when using a foreign key Django will use that as its mapping unless otherwise stated in the code.

Comment: Thanks Jack for answer. I can see if i generate sql for my model that django will create id as a primary key, but how does that answer the dropdown question i asked? So generated id will map to employee, but how it decides values of which field of Department to show in dropdown - dept_name, dept_head or dept_abbrv)

Comment: you have to declare that in your templates by say, iterating over the list that is returned from the query `for name in dept:`or even `for name, head, abbrev in dept`

Comment: your question is not very clear in what you are trying achieve, is your drodown being dispalyed and you dont know how? or are you trying work out how to get the values you need in the dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to specify the field on which you create your relationship. Django knows by himself that he must select the primary key (id) of the table associated with your model.

Django is responsible for creating the id itself. You can see the id in the migration files of your application.

[image: Model and migration]

Comment: Thanks Kevin for answer. I can see if i generate sql for my model that django will create id as a primary key, but how does that answer the dropdown question i asked? So generated id will map to employee, but how it decides values of which field of Department to show in dropdown - dept_name, dept_head or dept_abbrv? Right now it is showing dept_name which is not a primary key

Comment: @ManishJindal by default I think it shows the result of `__str__` on your model, although it is possible to override the label creation (did it once).

Comment: @Kevin I tested it. yes it is taking __ str __ by default. Thanks for help!